# Severe allergies to perfume and dust...laundry during 9 days and chol ha'moed?

Tags: tisha-bav, nine-days, chol-hamoed

Every year I just suffer rather than finding out if it's permitted. I haven't seen health reasons to permit doing laundry during this time. In addition, I am lodging in a house owned and occupied by a busy family. How on EARTH can I do laundry privately, even if it is permitted??